# what is the best way to delete mutiple nested keys from Immutable.js Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Is in the Immutable.JS any feature how to delete multiple keys from a Map?

Lets say I want delete all nested keys `c0`, `c1`, `c2` from the Immutable map in this example:

```
const x = fromJS({
  a1: 'A',
  a2: { b: { c0:'C0', c1:'C1' } },
  a3: { b:'B' },
  a4: { b: { c:'C', c1:'C1', c2:'C2' }},
  a5: { b: { c: { d:'D', d1:'D1' }}},
  a6: { b: { c2:'c2' }},
});
```

Is there any simple pure way how to do that?

My solution is this:

```js
const { fromJS, Map } = Immutable;

const x = fromJS({
  a1: 'A',
  a2: { b: { c0:'C0', c1:'C1' } },
  a3: { b:'B' },
  a4: { b: { c:'C', c1:'C1', c2:'C2' }},
  a5: { b: { c: { d:'D', d1:'D1' }}},
  a6: { b: { c2:'c2' }},
});

console.log(x.toJS());

const newX = x.map((value, key) => {
  if (Map.isMap(value)){
    value = value.hasIn(['b', 'c0']) ? value.deleteIn(['b', 'c0']) : value;
    value = value.hasIn(['b', 'c1']) ? value.deleteIn(['b', 'c1']) : value;
    value = value.hasIn(['b', 'c2']) ? value.deleteIn(['b', 'c2']) : value;
  } 
  return value;
});

console.log('----------------------------');
console.log(newX.toJS());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

But I don't like the variable reassigning in `value = value.hasIn(...` nor ESLint.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to check if the path exists ("If any keys in `keyPath` do not exist, no change will occur.", see the links below), so simply chain the calls

```
return value.deleteIn(['b', 'c0']).deleteIn(['b', 'c1']).deleteIn(['b', 'c2']);
```

Additionally, when you make multiple mutations it may be beneficial to use `withMutations`:

```
return value.withMutations(map => {
    map.deleteIn(['b', 'c0']).deleteIn(['b', 'c1']).deleteIn(['b', 'c2']);
});
```

References:

- https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/deleteIn
- https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/withMutations

Comment: Oh! Great, I didn't notice we can chain Immutable methods. Thank you also for example with `withMutations()` 

But I think you are not right in the thing that we don't need to check if path exists - at least the `deleteIn` throws error `Uncaught Error: invalid keyPath`.

you can try: https://codepen.io/webmato/pen/bwZjPa?editors=0012

Comment: @webmato "But I think you are not right in the thing that we don't need to check if path exists" --- well, it's complicated: `a3: { b: 'B' },` when you `deleteIn(['b', 'c1'])` it fails because `b` is not even an object. I think the fundamental problem with the example is unknown shape of the object. I believe if you shaped your data structure more strictly you would not need all those unnecessary checks. Otherwise, yep, you must check.